# Can you replace the harddrive of a Lenovo T440 with the harddrive from a Lenovo T490

Tags: replacement

Can you replace the harddrive of a Lenovo T440 with the harddrive from a Lenovo T490

Comment: Probably. But there are different models, and I doubt anyone can say much more than "probably" until we know which exact models you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It should fit. That series of ThinkPads used the same form factor for hard drives.

This is just for the drive. You most likely cannot move the operating system from the computer with the drive because (a) it is most likely OEM and (b) drivers will be different.